# How to create a line from 2 sf objects

Tags: r, geospatial, r-sf

I have 2 shapefiles that have the same number of rows. I want to create a line for each row.

I can't figure out how to do it.

Here is my example code

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.11.2, GDAL 3.6.2, PROJ 9.2.0; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
# For the sake of reproducibility
tab1 <- data.frame(
  long = c(-129, -80, -100),
  lat = c(56, 69, 60)
)
tab2 <- data.frame(
  long = c(-100, -90, -120),
  lat = c(59, 75, 62)
)
my_x <- sf::st_as_sf(tab1, coords = c("long", "lat"), crs = 4326)
my_y <- sf::st_as_sf(tab2, coords = c("long", "lat"), crs = 4326)

# I have to start with sf objects

my_x
#> Simple feature collection with 3 features and 0 fields
#> Geometry type: POINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -129 ymin: 56 xmax: -80 ymax: 69
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#>          geometry
#> 1 POINT (-129 56)
#> 2  POINT (-80 69)
#> 3 POINT (-100 60)
my_y
#> Simple feature collection with 3 features and 0 fields
#> Geometry type: POINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -120 ymin: 59 xmax: -90 ymax: 75
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#>          geometry
#> 1 POINT (-100 59)
#> 2  POINT (-90 75)
#> 3 POINT (-120 62)

sf::st_join(my_x, my_y)
#> Simple feature collection with 3 features and 0 fields
#> Geometry type: POINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -129 ymin: 56 xmax: -80 ymax: 69
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#>          geometry
#> 1 POINT (-129 56)
#> 2  POINT (-80 69)
#> 3 POINT (-100 60)

# Doesn't work. it just does all combinations...
sf::st_union(my_x, my_y)
#> Simple feature collection with 9 features and 0 fields
#> Geometry type: MULTIPOINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -129 ymin: 56 xmax: -80 ymax: 75
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#>                         geometry
#> 1 MULTIPOINT ((-100 59), (-12...
#> 2 MULTIPOINT ((-80 69), (-100...
#> 3 MULTIPOINT ((-100 60), (-10...
#> 4 MULTIPOINT ((-90 75), (-129...
#> 5 MULTIPOINT ((-80 69), (-90 ...
#> 6 MULTIPOINT ((-90 75), (-100...
#> 7 MULTIPOINT ((-120 62), (-12...
#> 8 MULTIPOINT ((-80 69), (-120...
#> 9 MULTIPOINT ((-100 60), (-12...


# I would like a linestring sf object of length 3
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

I have difficulty navigating through the complexity of sf. The resources are mostly overwhelming to me.

It is important to note that my objects are data frame (sf objects) I see that we can supply a matrix to `sf::st_linestring()`, but I can't use that solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For pairwise union you could use `st_union()` through `Map()` / `mapply()` , and if those input shapes include any attributes you'd like to keep, perhaps start with `cbind()` . `Map()` return value is a list of multipoints and it must be converted back to sfc, which in turn can be casted to linestrings:

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.11.2, GDAL 3.6.2, PROJ 9.2.0; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
tab1 <- data.frame(
  long = c(-129, -80, -100),
  lat = c(56, 69, 60)
)
tab2 <- data.frame(
  long = c(-100, -90, -120),
  lat = c(59, 75, 62)
)
my_x <- sf::st_as_sf(tab1, coords = c("long", "lat"), crs = 4326)
my_y <- sf::st_as_sf(tab2, coords = c("long", "lat"), crs = 4326)

xy <- cbind(my_x, my_y)
xy
#> Simple feature collection with 3 features and 0 fields
#> Active geometry column: geometry
#> Geometry type: POINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -129 ymin: 56 xmax: -80 ymax: 69
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#>          geometry      geometry.1
#> 1 POINT (-129 56) POINT (-100 59)
#> 2  POINT (-80 69)  POINT (-90 75)
#> 3 POINT (-100 60) POINT (-120 62)

xy$geom_line <- 
  Map(st_union, xy$geometry, xy$geometry.1) |> 
  st_as_sfc(crs = st_crs(xy)) |>
  st_cast("LINESTRING")

# switch active geometry to geom_line:
st_geometry(xy) <- "geom_line"
xy
#> Simple feature collection with 3 features and 0 fields
#> Active geometry column: geom_line
#> Geometry type: LINESTRING
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -129 ymin: 56 xmax: -80 ymax: 75
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#>          geometry      geometry.1                     geom_line
#> 1 POINT (-129 56) POINT (-100 59) LINESTRING (-129 56, -100 59)
#> 2  POINT (-80 69)  POINT (-90 75)   LINESTRING (-80 69, -90 75)
#> 3 POINT (-100 60) POINT (-120 62) LINESTRING (-100 60, -120 62)
```

Result:

```r
# without input geometries:
subset(xy, select = -c(geometry, geometry.1))
#> Simple feature collection with 3 features and 0 fields
#> Geometry type: LINESTRING
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -129 ymin: 56 xmax: -80 ymax: 75
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#>                       geom_line
#> 1 LINESTRING (-129 56, -100 59)
#> 2   LINESTRING (-80 69, -90 75)
#> 3 LINESTRING (-100 60, -120 62)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: It worked!! Thank you so much. I filed a feature request for sf https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/2259 and the maintainer seemed to be open to implement a simpler version of that.

Comment: Apparently, we can use st_union(st_geometry(my_x), st_geometry(my_y))

Comment: In sf 1.0-15, it will be possible to use st_union(x, y, by_feature = TRUE) to solve this!!

Comment: Actually updated [st_union](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/commit/13f4ce9a16987a4177a5c3de2718093ba0511c3a) on close of issue for those who install from source between releases. Linestring has been a weird  step child for many years. Edzer's comment on difference in how sf or sfc objects treated in st_union context is interesting and probably the crux.

Comment: @olivroy , nice! I believe you should consider adding `st_union(st_geometry(my_x), st_geometry(my_y))` as a separate answer. BTW,   this also allows us to do `cbind(my_x, my_y) |> mutate(geometry = st_union(geometry, geometry.1), .keep = "unused") |> st_cast("LINESTRING")`